# Grafana azure log analytics transfer query from logs

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-log-analytics

I have this query that works in Azure logs when i set the scope to the specific application insights I want to use

```
let usg_events = dynamic(["*"]);
let mainTable = union pageViews, customEvents, requests
    | where timestamp > ago(1d)
    | where isempty(operation_SyntheticSource)
    | extend name =replace("\n", "", name)
    | where '*' in (usg_events) or name in (usg_events)
;
let queryTable = mainTable;
let cohortedTable = queryTable
    | extend dimension =tostring(client_CountryOrRegion)
    | extend dimension = iif(isempty(dimension), "<undefined>", dimension)
    | summarize hll = hll(user_Id) by tostring(dimension)
    | extend Users = dcount_hll(hll)
    | order by Users desc
    | serialize rank = row_number()
    | extend dimension = iff(rank > 5, 'Other', dimension)
    | summarize merged = hll_merge(hll) by tostring(dimension)
    | project ["Country or region"] = dimension, Counts = dcount_hll(merged);
cohortedTable
```

but trying to use the same in grafana just gives an error.

```
"'union' operator: Failed to resolve table expression named 'pageViews'"
```

Which is the same i get in azure logs if i dont set the scope to the specific application insights resource. So my question is. how do i make it so grafana targets this specific scope inside the logs? The query jsut gets the countries of the users that log in

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Currently, there is no ***option/feature*** to add **Scope** in **Grafana**.

The **Scope** is available only in the ***Azure Log Analytics Workspace***.

If you want the **Feature/Resolution**, please raise a ticket in [Grafana Community](https://community.grafana.com/) where all the issues are officially addressed.